# Versprechen vs. in Aussicht stellen

Tags: meaning

Aus dem [Spiegel-Online](http://m.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/a-1015364.html#spRedirectedFrom=www&referrrer=https://www.google.com/):

> Washington - Nach einem Telefonat mit Bundeskanzlerin Angela Merkel (CDU) hat US-Präsident Barack Obama ein weiteres Hilfspaket für die Ukraine `in Aussicht gestellt`. Beide Politiker seien sich einig, dass Finanzhilfen zur wirtschaftlichen Stabilisierung des Krisenlandes wichtig seien, hieß es aus dem Weißen Haus. Der Internationale Währungsfonds solle die neuen Kredithilfen vorbereiten.

Ich wundere mich, dass der Ausdruck `in Aussicht stellen` dasselbe wie [`versprechen`](http://mobile-dictionary.reverso.net/deutsch-englisch/jdm%20etw%20in%20Aussicht%20stellen) in diesem Kontext ist:

Ich habe diesen Ausdruck in einem Online-Wörterbuch nachgeschaut und es bedeutet `to offer sth`. Was ist der Unterschied dazwischen?

Answer (score 4):

It's a metaphor. A literal translation would be "to put something into view". Imagine Obama together with the adressees of this statement high up on some tower, having a metaphorical look (view) into the future, and him "putting" another aid package on the horizon. Somehow like that.

The site [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=in+aussicht) has some suggestions, one of them being

> to hold out the prospect of sth. *(which is pretty accurate imo)*

and the [online Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Aussicht#Bedeutung2) does in fact explain it with *versprechen*. But the two are not really synonymous (except in the context of political rhetorics maybe).

"Make something a likely possibility", "That could happen" - however you paraphrase it, it has to be weaker than "promising". You can't *in Aussicht stellen* your parents that you'll learn for the upcoming exams, and not spend time on German.

Regarding "to offer something": More like it, though not in the sense of "I offer you 500 sesterces for your donkey", but rather as in "Look, if you sell me your donkey for 300 sesterces, I'll talk to my daugther about your son".

Comment: Danke für die Hilfe!

Comment: @DerPolyglott33 Bitte gerne, keine Ursache.